# Why can’t I open this webpage using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Why can’t I open this webpage using selenium?

I tried to open the webpage, but the display was blank. But if I paste the URL into other browsers, it can be opened. I don’t know whether it is a problem with the chrome driver or the webpage.

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver
url = 'http://www.customs.gov.cn/customs/syx/index.html'
browser = webdriver.Chrome() # (options = option)
browser.get(url)
```

Comment: What happens if you use an `https` URL?

Comment: Still blank ....